# How to modify the body response with Nginx and Javascript

Tags: nginx

I have a simple task but it seems hard to find the solution over the internet.

My goal is to modify/alter the response my Nginx proxy is returning to the caller, for example:
assuming the following GET http://somehost/somejsom
the actual response I got from my Nginx is a Json like this:

```
{
 "propA": "valueA",
 "propB": "valueB"
}
```

I need to change the value of "propA" to "valueC", or even simple perform the following replace operation:

```
replace("\"propA\": \"valueA\"", "\"propA\": \"valueC\"")
```

Bonus point if I can perform this replace only if the request body contains a specified value.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the (HTML) content / body by enabling the [nginx ngx_http_sub_module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html). That will also allow you to do simple string substitution.

A different method is with the [nginx_substitutions_filter](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/substitutions/) that also supports regular expressions